# TypeError: password() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python

I am trying to print a variable in a function and the variable is in another function.

Example

```
def function():
    password = blahblah
```

and

```
def function2():
    .....
    print password
```

I am relatively new to python and have tried several things and none have worked

Comment: 1. The code you posted does not produce the error you mention; 2. If you get an exception, always post the full traceback!

Comment: The code is an example of the code I have written.

Comment: That's a nice example, but sadly it doesn't have anything to do with the title of your question. I'll say that again with some capslock for emphasis: THE CODE YOU HAVE WRITTEN HERE CANNOT POSSIBLY PRODUCE THE ERROR IN THE QUESTION TITLE; AND IF YOU GET AN ERROR POST THE _EXACT_ ERROR MESSAGE IN FULL TEXT IN THE BODY OF YOUR QUESTION. Don't expect people to be able to help you if you don't.

Comment: umm they helped me..as for you.. you have issues dude

Comment: I have an issue with your question being nonsense. The title is an error message that can never arise from your example code. I don't get how you don't get this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created and accessed the variable within the scope of `function`, it gets destroyed once `function()` finishes executing.

```
password=None
def function():
  global password 
  password = blahblah

def function2(): 
  print password
```

A better way to do this would be:

```
def function():
  return blahblah

def function2(): 
  print function()
```

Comment: This worked for me.. So simple, i feel ridiculously stupid now lol

Comment: @AmaChurLOL: Great! (that it worked, not that you feel stupid :P)

Answer (score 0):

Return `password` from `function`, and use the returned value inside`function2`.

You can't access variables inside a function from outside the function, as they are local to that function.

```
def function(): 
    password = blahblah    # This variable is local to function
                           # and can't be accessed outside of the function

    return password        # But you can return the value of password using 
                           # the `return` statement.

def function2(): 
    print function()      #use the retured value from function
```

Comment: the first function is doing more than just setting a variable though, if i called the first function would that not print everything in that function?

Comment: @AmaChurLOL yes it would `print` if you're printing inside that function, and will ultimately return a value at the end of the function.(by default a function returns `None` in python).

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the variable as an argument to the second function, as follows

```
>>> def function():
        password = blahblah
        function2(password)
>>> def function2(passWord):
        print passWord
>>> function()
blahblah
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1():
    return 'blahblah'  #return value from given function



def function2(param):  # accept a parameter
    if callable(param):  # if is callable (ie. function)... 
         print param()   # ...print value by calling it
    else:
         print param     # otherwise print just the value

>>> function2(function1)
blahblah
```